# sqlite3 - insert - javascript object as values

Tags: javascript, sqlite, insert

**What is the easiest solution to use a javascript object as values for a sqlite3 insert?** The following code does not work.

```
const values = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 34,
  language: 'english'
};

db.run('INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?)', values, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('success');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need to write the SQL correctly.
To insert into the columns `name, age, language`,
you need to write the SQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (name, age, language) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

And pass the values of the 3 columns as parameters.

```
db.run('INSERT INTO tablename (name, age, language) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [values['name'], values['age'], values['language']]), (err) => { ... });
```

Or if the property names in the JavaScript object correspond directly to the column names, then you can generate the correct SQL string dynamically to have more flexibility:

```
const cols = Object.keys(values).join(", ");
const placeholders = Object.keys(values).fill('?').join(", ");
db.run('INSERT INTO tablename (' + cols + ') VALUES (' + placeholders + ')', Object.values(values)), (err) => { ... });
```

Comment: I tried it this way but: `Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table tablename has 4 columns but 1 values were supplied`

Comment: @tomole then you need to specify the name of the column in the SQL. For example, to insert into column named json: `INSERT INTO tablename (json) VALUES (?)`

Comment: Can u please specify what you mean with `json`?

Comment: @tomole what are the columns in the table, and in which columns do you want to insert which values?

Comment: columns are `name, age, language` and values are `'John', 34, 'english'`. I want to run `INSERT INTO tablename (name, age, language) VALUES ('John', 34, 'english');`

Comment: @tomole I understand your question better now. I rewrote my answer accordingly, I hope this helps.

Comment: exactly I was looking for. The dynamically version. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try `?,?,?` and `Obj.values()`
code.

```js
const values = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 34,
  language: 'english'
};
paramString = "?";
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(values).length -1 ; i ++) paramString += ",?";
// db.run('INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('+paramString + ')', Object.values(values));
 console.log('INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('+paramString + ')',Object.values(values));
```

Comment: querystring will end in `INSERT INTO tablename (name age language) VALUES (John 34 english)`. This wont work.

Comment: Thanks but: `Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table tablename has 3 columns but 1 values were supplied`.

Comment: Try  `...` operator `...Object.values(values)`

Comment: Still same error, because `console.log(...Object.values(values)` prints `John 34 english`. The commas are missing.

Comment: Okay. But for some reason there is still an argument mismatch.

Comment: Found out your problem, numberof params, try '?,?,?'.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're coming from `React Native` environment, inserting objects to `SQLite` works perfectly fine on `iOS`, and you even don't have to restructure the object.

However, for `SQLite` on `Android` behaves differently. Trying to insert an objects lags (at least my `Android` simulator) it so much, and there was no  single response from the `SQL` transaction. In addition to that, I had to pass into the parameters values from the destructured object, because doing so in the `SQL` query, like in the accepted answer, didn't work for me.

It's a really strange behaviour, but I've also noticed the app has started working way faster on the `Android` simulator after I've removed inserting the object to the `SQLite`.