# SQLite React Native db.executeSql() no response in Android Sim

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, react-native-sqlite-storage

I have a strange problem. I installed [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage) like described on their docs (with autolinking and with the bundled SQLite, not androids SQLite, since it doesn't support JSON functions). Now everything works fine on iOS (Simulator and Physical) and on Android (Physical). But only on Android Simulator (not on my Pixel 3a) I get following issue:
When running a basic query (which works on iOS and my Pixel 3a, but no on the Pixel 3a Sim) it just never returns anything when using :

```
print('Print 1')
await db.executeSql(`SELECT VALUE
                     FROM ${reportTableName}`); // Same happens with empty query: ''
print('Print 2')
```

Output (Pixel 3a Simulator):

```
Print 1
```

Output (Physical Pixel 3a, iOS Simulator, Physical iPhone):

```
Print 1
Print 2
```

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening? It seems as if I'm the only one with this problem...

**Simulator (also tried Pixel 4):**
Device: Pixel 3a
Android Version: 12
Build Nr.: SE1A.220203.002.A1
React Native: v0.68.1
react-native-sqlite-storage: v6.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, was able to find the issue. After further inspecting the issue it seems to throw an error `Invalid Database handle`. After further investigation I found [this solution](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/issues/496#issuecomment-963869396). But this was not an option since I had to use the SQLite database bundled in the library (which this configuration handles) because I need FTS5 support for functions such as `json_set()`.

So instead I switched [`react-native-sqlite-2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-2) which uses a newer version of sqlite. Problem fixed!

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was when I've been trying inserting `JavaScript` object to the `SQLite` table. `SQLite` for `iOS` can handle this very well, but for unknown reason `SQLite` for `Android` not at all.

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73404423/11127383

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Hmm interesting behaviour, but don't think this is the issue in my case, since a simple await db.executeSql('') doesn't seem to work either.
I guess it has something to do with the bundled SQLite database of the library. But not a huge issue...